# Jinja doubles the content in for loop

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm looping through the list of names and want to put it in html.
The problems is that Jinja doubles the

. One with the name value, but the other one is just empty. Why is it happening?

Here is python code

```
import os

from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "secret"
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"

Users = ['Bob', 'Nick', 'Alice', 'Brian']

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template ("test.html", Users=Users)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>User list</p>
    <ul id="user_list">
      {% for name in Users %}
        <li>{{ name }}<li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

[And here is the output I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ml6g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just didn't close the < li >  tag in you test.html file:

```
    <li>{{ name }}<li>
```